# c++ compile error linker command failed

Tags: c++, xcode, templates

I am new to C++ and I am not familiar to build a c++ project.
I want to write a simple Vector Class(not the default c++ vector) so I write a test program.

This is my header file("Vector.h")

```
# define Vector_H
typedef int Rank;
template <typename T> class Vector {
protected:
    Rank _size; int _capacity;  T* _elem;
    void copyFrom ( T const* A, Rank lo, Rank hi );
public:
    Vector ( T const* A, Rank n ) { copyFrom ( A, 0, n ); }
    T& operator[] ( Rank r ) const;
};
```

This is my Vector.cpp file:

```
#include "Vector.h"
typedef int Rank;
template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::copyFrom ( T const* A, Rank lo, Rank hi ) {
    _elem = new T[_capacity = 2 * ( hi - lo ) ]; _size = 0;
    while ( lo < hi )
        _elem[_size++] = A[lo++];
}

template <typename T>
T& Vector<T>::operator[] ( Rank r ) const
{ return _elem[r]; }
```

And this my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a[10]={1,3,5,7,9};
    Vector<int> c(a,5);
    cout<<c[4]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When i put this 3 file into my Xcode project, it returns error:
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
and I don't know how to do with this.
My Code works fine if I  put all this to a single cpp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

template definition cannot split in different files. you should copy everything in Vector.cpp to your Vector.h. Or rename the Vector.cpp to anything but *.cpp (maybe Vector.imp), then add #include "Vector.imp" in the end of Vector.h.

Comment: The problem is sloved!